# Search for Pixel on screen

Tags: c#, search, find, screen, pixel

I want to find a specific pixel coordinates from screen. Here's my code (I'm mega-super-newbie, I just started today with C#:

```
static string GetPixel(int X, int Y)
{
    Point position = new Point(X, Y);
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    graphics.CopyFromScreen(position, new Point(0, 0), new Size(1, 1));

    var _Pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
    return "0x" + _Pixel.ToArgb().ToString("x").ToUpper().Remove(0, 2);
    //it returns a pixel color in a form of "0xFFFFFF" hex code
    //I had NO idea how to convert it to hex code so I did that :P
}

static void Main()
{
    // for x = 1 to screen width...
    for (int x = 1; x <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom; x++)
    {
        // for x = 1 and y = 1 to screen height...
        for (int y = 1; y <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height; y++)
        {
            string pixel = GetPixel(x, y);
            if (pixel == "0x007ACC") //blue color
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found 0x007ACC at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");
                break; //exit loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit:
Here's an error which appears when I run this script:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location
>   within the string

I have experience in AutoIt, it's my first day with C# ^^
Regards

Comment: Why are you downvoting this question. I did a lot of research to write that piece of code. It's really hard to write something like that for a guy with no C# experience at all.

Comment: The conversion to string is pointless imho, why do you want to do that? I guess you want to work with the color, so keep it as an int the int doesn't say if it is hex or decimal or what not it just doesn't matter at that point. Also don't create the bitmap everytime again and again, just do it once above your x and y loop.

Comment: And your loops should start at 0, not 1 and your condition should be "less" not "less or equal" width/height of the screen. This must be the problem aswell.

Comment: As I said I'm mostly scripting in AutoIt, where I use hex color codes, oh and yes, I will change that 'less' for my loop :)

Comment: I'm just saying that you are building a string in a very inefficient matter for every pixel on the screen, while you could just use the int, you can later still convert it to a hex string if you really need it. But that hex would be a string. for example it is perfectly valid to write int number = 0xFF; in c#. Because the way how you write the number is not important. In your case you are converting it to a string, which is very performance costly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Most coordinates and other things are 0-based, just as in arrays.

That being said, it would be best to use the Bounds' X/Y/Width and Height properties for the loops:

```
var bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
for (int x = bounds.X; x < bounds.Width; x++) {
  for(int y = bounds.Y; y < bounds.Height; y++) {
    ..
```

And the proper way to convert the ARGB value to hex is to use the [string.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method:

`string hex = string.Format("0x{0:8x}", argb);`

**EDIT:** Apparently `Graphics.CopyFromScreen` leaks handles like there's no tomorrow, which causes strange exceptions to be thrown when no more handles are available ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/474450b9-e260-4369-9efb-0d57a5b2e06d/))

A quick workaround for your scenario could be to capture the whole screen once and then search in the bitmap, i.e. `Graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Position(0, 0), new Position(0, 0), new Size(bounds.Width, bounds.Height));`

Unfortunately this didn't get fixed in .Net 4.0 (don't know about 4.5), so the only proper solution seems to be to P/Invoke the native GDI functions, as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/474450b9-e260-4369-9efb-0d57a5b2e06d/).

Comment: I still have one problem with the script. Would you mind to see what's wrong with it?
http://pastebin.com/DDAy6ez3
I get an error:
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is incorrect.
Line: graphics.CopyFromScreen(position, new Point(0, 0), new Size(1, 1));`
That's odd, I get this error when loop reaches "{X = 4 Y = 891}".

Comment: Still nothing, it stops at 4,891 all the time for no reason.